# ASP.net web service on server sometimes doesn't load

Tags: asp.net, web-services

We have an ASP.net web service (.asmx) up on our server that one of our clients uses to get data from us.

They've been complaining about timeout issues occurring now and then. I decided to check out my code to see if anything could be causing the issue.

I went to our .asmx url using my internet explorer and saw that it just kept loading. This is the second time that I've noticed this happen. I just can't connect to the .asmx page. I get no error message, just keeps loading.

Now obviously, this would cause timeout errors for their client program as the service is unreachable. Any idea why this could be happening??

Also, where are the asp.net error logs usually stored on the server??? Is it in the same directory as the .asmx?? And do these error logs get generated automatically or do I have to put something in my code??

**EDIT: Forgot to mention that the server where my web service resides is a Linux based server. I had to use MonoDevelop to package it for such.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the application event viewer on the server.  If any errors are occuring at the service level, you'll see them posted there.  Timeout processes can be tricky to debug.  If there are server resources that are being vied for by other application pools, this application might be getting the shaft.  I would look at process usage of memory and cpu at the server first.  If all looks well there, check into IIS and see what other applications reside with your service.  If it is all good there, then I would look into your code for long running possibilities.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is running on a Linux based server. I will add this to my question.

Comment: Same advice, just switch out IIS for Apache and switch the concept of applications for the httpd process.  Since all Apache (usually) runs under one process, check the memory usage of httpd before and after the call to the service.  Also, the httpd.log will have any info on timeouts, etc.